# Android NDK C++ stlport

Tags: android, c++11, android-ndk

Currently I'm using NDK-r10c with C++11 support through gnustl. Unfortunately our project need to switch to stlport. While changing from gnustl to stlport many errors raised during compilation. Below is **Application.mk** file.

```
APP_PLATFORM            := android-18 
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION   := 4.8 
APP_ABI                 := armeabi-v7a 
APP_STL                 := stlport_static
# APP_STL               := gnustl_static 
APP_CPPFLAGS            := -std=c++11 
ifeq ($(NDK_DEBUG),1) 
APP_OPTIM               := debug 
else 
APP_OPTIM               := release
endif
```

It seems that C++11 features are not available:
 - cbegin(), cend() on vectors 
 - data() on vectors, 
 - cannot deduce auto from cbegin(), etc.

Comment: What is wrong with gnustl for you? I am asking because I have been using it for a while by default, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I was always using gnustl but stlport is a requirement from the client.

Comment: @AlexCohn - many companies don't want GPL'd components because of the legal problems it creates. When free-lancing I often have to sign contracts with a no-GPL clause. I'm even aware of companies which have policies that explicitly forbid examining GPL code, even in bug reports.

Comment: Now open in the AOSP bug tracker: [Issue 216331: STLport does not support C++11](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216331).

Comment: @jww gnustl in spite of its name, is not GPL, it's [LGPL v.3 with extra relaxed exemption](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24832164/192373).

Answer (score 3):

STLport is just too old and does not support C++11 at all.

Flags like -std=c++11 will affect the compiler only, not necessarily the STL implementation.

You will have to use either gnustl or libc++

Comment: How do you use libc++ on Android? I don't see clang support as one of the options to APP_STL.

Answer (score 0):

To use stlport you will need add these lines in your Android.mk

```
# Need this line to allow use alloc on stl containers
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D_STLP_USE_NEWALLOC

# c++11 support
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11

# for stl port
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lstdc++

# include stl headers
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ${NDK_ROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport
```

Comment: Alex, the is still problem like before:
error: 'move' is not a member of 'std',
error: 'sort' was not declared in this scope

Comment: @Alex - STLport is also missing `<mutex>`, `<atomics>`, etc.